# Appearance of numbers for an ordered list element starting with a code block

Tags: bug, design, code-formatting, list

These:

````
1. ```
   foo
   bar
   baz
   bad
   ```
2.     foo
       bar
       baz
       bad
````

Render as:

1. ```
   foo
   bar
   baz
   bad
   ```
2. ```
   foo
   bar
   baz
   bad
   ```

Screenshot:

> [image]

I am pretty sure the list numbers were aligned with the first line in the past, but I don't have an screenshot of an older entry. Preferably they should be, instead of being somewhere near the second line of the code block.

Browser:

- This was seen on Firefox Developer Edition (78.0b4 (64-bit)) on macOS 10.15.4
- Renders fine on Chrome on the same system
- Numbers don't appear at all on Safari 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8):

  > [image]

First saw this while editing on U&L.

Comment: Fine on Chrome here on Windows 10 too.

Comment: Just like @TheLethalCoder I have Windows 10 and Chrome but I'm not having the problem. Try using your browser on full-screen and on a smaller window and give the results.

Comment: The screenshots were taken when fullscreen (I think 2880x1800 for a 2019 15" MBP?). Resizing the window small enough to trigger the mobile view didn't make any difference to the alignment.

Comment: repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 77.0.1